# linear objective function with non-linear constraints and binary variables

Tags: matlab, optimization, binary, constraints, linear-programming

I have a problem where I need to optimize a choice of candidates. Each candidate has a score (between 0 and 1), a type (10 choices from 1 to 10) and a quantity.

My variables to optimize are binary. They represent the choice or not of the candidate. The object function is linear, it is the scalar product of the binary variable and a score vector. The idea is to select the highest sum of score.

Now I have a linear constraint: the number of candidate that can be selected can be at most 35.

BUT i have also 10 non-linear constraints: there are 10 type of candidates. In the final selection, the total quantity of each type should be at most 10% of the total quantity of all type.

I have therefore wrote a code using `intlinprog` because it handles binary variables but I am struggling to deal with the non-linear constraints. I am not sure whether it would be best to try to linearize them or maybe use another solver?

here is the code:

```
rng('default');

clc;
clear;
n = 100;
maxSize =  35;
nbType = 10;
NAV = 6000000;
thresholdType = 0.1 * NAV;

%%%TOP BASKET
score = rand(n,1)/10+0.9;
quantity = rand(n,1)*300000;
type = ceil(rand(n,1)*nbType);
typeMask = zeros(n,nbType);

for i=1:nbType
    typeMask(:,i) = type(:,1) == i;
end

f = -score;
intcon = [1:1:n];

%Write the linear INEQUALITY constraints: 
A = [ones(1,n);bsxfun(@times,typeMask,quantity)'/thresholdType];
b = [maxSize;ones(nbType,1)];

%Write the linear EQUALITY constraints:
Aeq = [];
beq = [];

%Write the BOUND constraints: 
lb = zeros(n,1);
ub = ones(n,1); % Enforces i1,i2,...in binary

%x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
x = intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
```

The Problem is, in my A,b, the first constraint is the linear one (at most 35 candidates) and the last 10 are non-linear so it obviously does not give the right result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use a linear partition algorithm.

How does it work:

1. Sort the elements in descending order
2. Take the first K elements and put them into different sets (where k = typeq)
3. For the next N-K elements, put them in the set with the lowest sum

You're done.

This algorithm is not supposed to give you the solution that minimize the variance between the sum of each quantity for each type. But this is a good approximation, especially when `maxSize` and `n` are big.

You can also just calculate all the possible combination of k element in a set of n element (35|100) with combnk(35,100). Then you can check which combination give you the smallest variance, but of course this method is time consuming.

```
clc;
clear;
n = 1000;
maxSize =  400;
typeq = 10;

%creation of the dataset
id = 1:n;
quantity = rand(n,1)*1000;
type = ceil(rand(n,1)*typeq);

%sort the vectors
[quantity,rank]  = sort(quantity,'descend');
type = type(rank);
id = id(rank);

% Get the id of the 10 biggest quantities for the 10 different types
[~,b] = unique(flipud(type));
b = (n-b)+1;


if length(b) < typeq
    error('Not enough type') %mean that all the type are not represented.
end

ids = id(b);
types = type(b);
quantitys = quantity(b);

%Now we add the biggest remaining quantity to the type that have the smallest sum(quantity per type)
for i = typeq+1:maxSize
[~,minq]  = sort(accumarray(types,quantitys,[],@sum));
quantity(b) = [];
type(b) = [];
id(b) = [];

b = find(type==minq(1),1);

%if there is no more value for the type that have the smallest sum(quantity) we take the second smallest type, the third.... until that the type still exist.
ii = 2;
while isempty(b)
    b = find(type == minq(ii),1);
    ii = ii+1;
    disp('Variance is going to increase')
end

ids = [ids(:);id(b)];
types = [types(:);type(b)];
quantitys = [quantitys(:);quantity(b)];
end

% the selected ID
id_selected  = sort(ids);
% The sum for each type.
res = accumarray(types,quantitys,[],@sum);
cnt = accumarray(types,ones(maxSize,1),[],@sum);
for i = 1:typeq
    fprintf('The total quantity for type %d = %f and we have %d elements of this type\n',i,res(i),cnt(i))
end
```

Comment: Would you say that it is better in term of speed? Here n will be at most 200. So not extremely big. And some type might not be represented as well.

Comment: Yeah but `combnk`produce `n!/k!(n – k)!` rows... so for n = 200 it will be endless.

Comment: I was more thinking about using the intlinprog function from matlab which does actually quite well the job. But I will test both.

Comment: Perhaps i'm wrong but I don't understand how you can solve your problem with `intlinprog`. This function can solve a system of linear equations with constraints but not a repartition problem.

Comment: It is a selection problem. Find the best selection under constraints. I have updated the code above which is now giving me the solution for my current problem.

Answer (score -1):

For clarification: every type of candidate can be featured not more than 10% the number of total candidates? That is, for e.g. 33 total candidates, the maximum number of candidates per type is 3.3? Translated into logicals, the maximum amounts to 3 selections, thus a total of 30.
If I correctly understand your description, your constraints system results in every type featuring the same number of candidates and a fraction of exactly 10% of the total candidates, and the total number of candidates must be an integer multiple of 10.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. For clarification you can write your question in a comment.

Comment: No, I cannot, because you won't let me.

Comment: No, it is a bit more complicated than that. Each candidate has a quantity attached to it. Then the sum of quantity of each selected candidate of one type  can't be more than 10% of the total quantity of all selected candidates of all type. Basically, at the end of the optimization, i want to look at my optimized selection (max 35 candidates) and that when I sum the quantity for all candidate of 1 type, this value is less or equal than 10% of the sum of the quantity of all candidates selected. Hope it is clearer?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Anyway, as you describe it, the summed quantity of each candidate type needs to equal exactly 10% of the total quantity in order to meet your constraints (Total quantity equals sum of quantity for candidate types 1-10; individual candidate quantity <= 0.1 * total quantity). So your inequality constraint is actually an equality constraint.

Comment: THanks for bringing that up. I had actually miss-interpreted the problem. Actually the type cap is not based on the total of the selected quantity but a fix value which is given. Therefore those constraints become simple linear inequality and therefore my current problem is solved.